# Match group multiple times with regex

Tags: .net, regex

My goal is to get season and episode(s) of a TV show from filename. I have following regex:

```
(\d{1,2})([^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))+.*
```

Results are as expected for files containing only one episode. First matched group contains season number and third group contains episode number. But I have problems with files containg multiple episodes. It always matches only one group with episode (the last one) and not all of them.

Maybe example is better than thousands words:

```
S01E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4       Result: 01, 01
S01E01E02.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4    Result: 01, 02   Expected: 01, 01, 02
S01E01-02.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4    Result: 01, 02   Expected: 01, 01, 02
S01E01-E02.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4   Result: 01, 02   Expected: 01, 01, 02

01x01 Lorem ipsum.avi          Result: 01, 01
01x01-02 Lorem ipsum.avi       Result: 01, 02   Expected: 01, 01, 02

1x1 Lorem ipsum.avi            Result: 1, 1
1x1-2 Lorem ipsum.avi          Result: 1, 2     Expected: 1, 1, 2
```

Interactive example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/sJ7aT7/1).

I think that problem is in my (wrong) assumption that `+` in `([^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))+` will cause multiple group matches.

Btw I'm using .NET, but that should not matter I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed your regex to match the parts you need:

```
(\d{1,2})[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2})(?:[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))?.*
```

No need for multiline option in this case.

See my [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pE2lA9/1).

C# sample code:

```
var rx5 = new Regex(@"(\d{1,2})[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2})(?:[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))?.*");
var results = rx5.Matches(str5).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value + " - " + p.Groups[2].Value + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Groups[3].Value) ? " - " + p.Groups[3].Value : "")).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works for the samples I wrote here. But I probably wasn't very specific about the episodes count. Although it is rare, there migh be file named S01E02E03. Therefore I wanted something that will match any number of episodes.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to match: `(\d{1,2})[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2})(?:[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))?.*` also covers `S01E02E03`: it gets `01`, `02`, `03`. See https://regex101.com/r/pE2lA9/2. Or do you also want to match the letters denoting episodes? Which one? We cannot help you better if you do not provide all the data you have, *exact* desired output format. I think I did answer your question put this and not that way.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the confusion. I made a mistake in my previous comment. There should be `S01E01E02E03`. I know I can adjust your regex with another group to cover even 3 episodes. But I was wondering if there is a way to make it independent from number of episodes. Also, I don't need to match letters, just numbers.

Comment: I think I can do it another way, but for now, I think you could just add another optional group: `(\d{1,2})[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2})(?:[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))?(?:[^\d]{1,2}(\d{1,2}))?.*` https://regex101.com/r/pE2lA9/3. Another solution requires more code writing, and a regex will be the least serious part in it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this regex, but you have to use .NET to filter some useless matches.

```
([xES]|\b)(\d{1,2})
```

This will work for flexible number of Season or Episode on the same line.

Example of match:

```
S01E01E02E03
S01E01E02E03E04
...
```

But for instance, given:

```
S01E01E02E03.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4
```

This will match:
01, 01, 02, 03, 26

So you have to write a code to check if numbers are consecutive.